# Why do we use the term "uncorrelated" to describe linear dependence/independence?

Tags: correlation, random-variable, covariance, independence, linear

Terminologically, "uncorrelated" to me means that 2 things have no relationship, not necessarily constrained to linear relationships.

However, in statistics, we seem to confine "uncorrelated" to mean 2 things have no linear relationship, but could be related through other relationships. Why is this the convention?

For example, consider $X$ to be a uniform distribution symmetric about $[-1,1]$ and $Y=X^2$, it can be easily shown that $cov(X,Y)=0$, which means $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated by the statistical definition, but the 2 variables are clearly related through a polynomial relationship.

Comment: You are correct: zero correlation does not imply no relationship, just zero correlation.

Comment: @NickCox Right, but I guess my point is, I feel like in the English language, we typically think of correlation to be synonymous to having a relationship, so I was curious to see why statistics constrained the definition of correlation to be in the context of linearity only.

Comment: If anything it's the other way round. Although "correlation" was a word in English before it was hijacked (19th C) and given statistical meaning it seems to me that now very many of its uses informally in English are mangled echoes (mixed metaphor that) of its statistical and scientific senses. Either way "uncorrelated" should always mean "zero correlation" if the author is statistically well-informed but it may well mean "lacking a relationship" otherwise. Only the context and in extreme cases the authors if accessible can help you.

Comment: Parameter and significance are other words often mangled by journalists, politicians,  and many scientists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Correlation" has a technical definition, which is the one used in statistics. It usually refers to the Pearson product-moment correlation. Correlation is one measure of *association*; indeed, it is one of the simplest and most used measures of association, which is probably why it is used in common parlance when "association" is more technically accurate today (because it includes relationships not well described by the Pearson correlation). Your understanding, as you have explained it, of "uncorrelated" reflects this convention. It is possible that the common use of "correlated" precedes the statistical use, but that is a matter regarding the history and sociolinguistics of science on which I have no authority.

If you are engaged in statistical or scientific discourse where precision is important, you should change your understanding of the word "uncorrelated" to mean "having a Pearson correlation of zero" and use the word "unassociated" to represent the lack of a relationship, not just a linear relationship, between phenomena.

Comment: Is "unassociated" formal terminology? I just tried googling for it, but didn't see anything come up besides this stackexchange post :)

Comment: I think I would more willingly write "not associated" except that when talking about results the wording would be more likely to be "weakly associated" or some such.

Comment: I use it in my writing because I think its meaning is clear and it expresses a positive statement (i.e., "x is something" rather than "x is not something"), but I don't know how common it is. I think "independent" is approximately (if not exactly) equivalent and used far more often. To me it's the clearest antonym of "associated".